# How to run browser in background in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, cron, javascript

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and PHP. I have 2 files:

1. `test.html` - content java to test network
2. `update.php` - the test file will post result to update database.

I need to run and execute an URL address in the background, and then close it after completing a javascript task.

Basically this URL (http://test.html) does a network testing task to test the HTTP port then sends the post result to the other URL (http://update.php) to save it in the database.

If I open the URL manually using a web browser the the system works fine. The problem now is, I want to invoke the URL from the CLI so that I can run it with cron.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Pass it as an argument to the browser, just like you would open a file.

Comment: basically i try to use curl to run the http://test.html, but it failed to executed the http://update.php. any other option?

Comment: Have you tried passing it as a browser argument as I said? curl doesn't process documents, just downloads them.